# Form Google Maps URL that searches for a specific places near specific coordinates

Tags: url, google-maps

I have the longitude and latitude and the name of the place I want to look for. How do I edit the Google Maps URL so that I obtain all the places (name of the places) near a set of coordinates?

I know I could do this using Google Map API, but just for a link seems a lot of trouble.

Comment: Why the coordinates? Why not just the street address?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You can use the query parameter `ll` for your lat and long, and you can use the query parameter `q` for what you want to search.

http://maps.google.com/?ll=39.774769,-74.86084

Or you can

http://maps.google.com/?q=your+query

Comment: It's something between the 2  goes like this http://maps.google.com/?q=ThePlace&sll=latitude,longitude where sll is the bussiness lat longitude, full parameter description on http://www.querystring.org/google/google-maps/google-maps-query-string-parameters, and wikipedia got some stuff about the subject. tanks Nick

Comment: what about zoom level with latitude and logitude

Comment: The above URL is now out of date but redirects fine. The current URL structure is: 

https://www.google.com/maps/search/your+query

Answer (score 83):

Yeah, I had the same question for a long time and I found the perfect one. Here are some parameters from it.

```
https://maps.google.com/?parameter=value
```

**q=**

Used to specify the search query in Google maps search.
eg :

```
https://maps.google.com/?q=newyork or
https://maps.google.com/?q=51.03841,-114.01679
```

**near=**

> Used to specify the location instead of putting it into q. Also has
>   the added effect of allowing you to increase the AddressDetails
>   Accuracy value by being more precise. Mostly only useful if q is a
>   business or suchlike.

**z=**

Zoom level. Can be set 19 normally, but in certain cases can go up to 23.

**ll=**

Latitude and longitude of the map centre point. Must be in that order. Requires decimal format. Interestingly, you can use this without q, in which case it doesn’t show a marker.

**sll=**

Similar to ll, only this sets the lat/long of the centre point for a business search. Requires the same input criteria as ll.

**t=**

Sets the kind of map shown. Can be set to:

```
m – normal  map
k – satellite
h – hybrid
p – terrain
```

**saddr=**

Sets the starting point for directions searches. You can also add text into this in brackets to bold it in the directions sidebar.

**daddr=**

Sets the end point for directions searches, and again will bold any text added in brackets.You can also add "+to:" which will set via points. These can be added multiple times.

**via=**

Allows you to insert via points in directions. Must be in CSV format. For example, via=1,5 addresses 1 and 5 will be via points without entries in the sidebar. The start point (which is set as 0), and 2, 3 and 4 will all show full addresses.

**doflg=**

Changes the units used to measure distance (will default to the standard unit in country of origin). Change to ptk for metric or ptm for imperial.

**msa=**

Does stuff with My Maps. Set to 0 show defined My Maps, b to turn the My Maps sidebar on, 1 to show the My Maps tab on its own, or 2 to go to the new My Map creator form.

*reference : http://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters*

Comment: Great answer! I had been looking for a list of parameters and I found it here

Comment: You may want to update your urls to use https instead of http

Answer (score 31):

additional info:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:
put in latitude and longitude after, example:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:51.03841,-114.01679

this will show pointer on map, but will suppress geocoding of the address, best for a location without an address, or for a location where google maps shows the incorrect address.

Comment: I wanted a pin - this answer gives you a pin on the geo point

Answer (score 9):

As of Jan 2018 (*update: still works in May 2023*) the latest URL is:

**https://google.com/maps/search/*your search string*** *(address, landmark, city, etc. Spaces are ok)*

Examples:

[https://google.com/maps/search/**empire state building**](https://google.com/maps/search/empire%20state%20building)

[https://google.com/maps/search/**1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500**](https://google.com/maps/search/1600%20Pennsylvania%20Ave%20NW,%20Washington,%20DC%2020500)

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for! thanks!

Comment: I wonder why there's no way to "help" GeoCoder in specifying what search field matches what category, e.g.: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=[country]=Switzerland&[street]=Gabenstrasse...`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new URL for Google Maps: https://www.google.com/maps/@39.774769,-74.86084,18z
equivalent to http://maps.google.com/?ll=39.774769,-74.86084.

39.774769 is the latitude and -74.86084 is longitude and 18z is 18 zoom level.

Answer (score 4):

Google now has a documentation page dedicated to Maps URLs:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

An API key is not required.

Manipulating one of the examples, I came up with this URL scheme that fits your question:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/<search term>/@<coordinates>,<zoom level>z
```

A valid example of this would be:

https://www.google.com/maps/search/pizza/@41.089988,-81.542901,12z

This should show you all of the pizza places around Akron, Ohio.