# google maps link

Tags: google-maps

I want to place a link on my website that links to google maps,
however I can't find information on how to form the url.
I have lat and lng coordinates and I want a marker to show the exact point.

I have this for example
    http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?hl=en&ll=55.236865,-1.616422&z=15
but it shows no marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=Via+Celadina,+4,+24125+Bergamo+Bergamo,+Lombardy,+Italy&sll=6.315299,14.414063&sspn=123.405342,329.0625&ie=UTF8&cd=1&geocode=0,45.688764,9.709610&ll=45.689094,9.709618&spn=0.00676,0.020084&t=h&z=16&iwloc=addr](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=Via%20Celadina,%204,%2024125%20Bergamo%20Bergamo,%20Lombardy,%20Italy&sll=6.315299,14.414063&sspn=123.405342,329.0625&ie=UTF8&cd=1&geocode=0,45.688764,9.709610&ll=45.689094,9.709618&spn=0.00676,0.020084&t=h&z=16&iwloc=addr)

And also 
[http://asnsblues.blogspot.com/2011/11/google-maps-query-string-parameters.html/](http://asnsblues.blogspot.com/2011/11/google-maps-query-string-parameters.html)

Stack:
[Google maps URL. I want to create a URL to google maps. I want to show search near specific coordonates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018060/google-maps-url-i-want-to-create-a-url-to-google-maps-i-want-to-show-search-ne)

Comment: brillaint thanks, i managed to do it by posting the lat/lng as query parameter but this is much better

Answer (score 1):

This can be done even easier now: https://google.com/maps/place/55.236861,-1.616417

Answer (score 0):

all the googlemap api are define [here](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/index.html)

http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?hl=en&ll=55.236865,-1.616422&z=15&q=@55.236865,-1.616422

Comment: i'm not using the api, i'm simply trying to form a url. Using your logic, every question can be answered wiith a link to google, so thanks

Comment: k i'll look for help you with only url use